# Dependency Injection of services into an Entity Framework Core database context

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

I have been attempting to use DI to inject services into my DB Context. For example, a User Resolver service for audit logging purposes. I have some extensions to ChangeTracker that audit created, modified and deleted properties and also an audit logger that logs the changed properties of the entity. For these to work effectively and seamlessly I need to determine the logged in user. In EF Core 1.1, I got this working by simply adding my IUserResolverService to the constructor.

When I attempted to upgrade to 2.0, I started to run into all sorts of issues as the tooling did not handle the extended constructor. I eventually removed it and everything started working, but without a reliable way of determining the logged in user.

I have tried to find an answer to this on many occasions now, and searching only uncovers a mountain of articles about injecting the context itself into things like controllers.

Can this be achieved in EF Core without breaking tooling, etc.? Is there a way to inject a service through Startup ConfigureServices?

Comment: I think that the fact that you can only find information on injecting the `DbContext` into other services is a bit of a clue... In my mind, I would want my `DbContext` instance to be a model of my database, and not depend on higher level services. Could you post an example of why you need to know if a user is logged in in your `DbContext`?

Comment: @EricSondergard I have some automatic audit features built into my context, to audit who did what, you need to know the who.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. If it's any help, I have done this same thing in the past, but instead by accessing the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` object, which was a `ClaimsIdentity` that had a claim with the current user's ID value in it. Then I used that to update the updated by/modified by properties of the entity. Doesn't really solve your problem directly as I'm sure you'd rather keep that logic in your service instance, which makes sense.

Comment: If you include audit properties (Created, Modified, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy) on the entities being changed then you can use this to create your audit log records in your `SaveChanges()` override.

Comment: @Brad I have used shadow properties for these values as they are not needed for 99% of user functionality, but can be accessed when needed. I am using the SaveChanges override, but I don't want to have the developer to manually set these values, or necessarily even be able to. The goal is to have it as seamless as possible.

Comment: @EricSondergard yes I think you get what I am trying to achieve, but what I want is to not rely on the Context to go and interrogate the Identity from the Thread. Using the resolver service, if I was using a WindowsPrincipal, or even a custom one, the resolver service would be responsible for that and just giving the context what it needs, which is what is the identity (username, display name, email, etc.) of the logged in user. So the context can be agnostic as to what type of authentication is in use.

Comment: Perhaps my answer here can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975297/updating-common-field-with-user-email/47980720#47980720

Comment: Have you tried the factory method of creating your DbContext?  i.e. `services.AddScoped<MyDbContext>(provider => new MyDbContext(provider.GetService<DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>>(), provider.GetService<IUserResolverService>()));`.

Comment: @Brad - [AddDbContext](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/093e30fdd83776bda0275c27cf596f390c3ac763/src/EFCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L476-L500) does a bit more than that.

Comment: @NightOwl888 not much more and it is easy to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar situation.  I ended up just injecting it manually in Startup but still resolving the dependencies.  I don't love this and wish the services would be injected into the DbContext constructor.  Here is my solution below:

```
public interface IUserContextProvider {
  User GetCurrentUser();
}


public class MvcUserContextProvider : IUserContextProvider {

  protected IHttpContextAccessor Accessor { get; set; }

  public MvcUserContextProvider(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
    Accessor = accessor;
  }
  public User GetCurrentUser() {
    //  Probably need some error handling and Special case pattern when
    // context is null.
    return (User) Accessor.HttpContext.User.Identity;
  }
}


public interface IEntityFrameworkOverrides {
  void EntityInitializing(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, IMutableEntityType entity);

  void EntityChanged(EntityEntry entity);
}


public abstract class UserAwareOverride : IEntityFrameworkOverrides {
  protected IUserContextProvider UserProvider { get; private set; }
  protected UserAwareOverride(IUserContextProvider userProvider)
  {
    UserProvider = userProvider;
  }
  public abstract void EntityInitializing(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, IMutableEntityType entity);

  public abstract void EntityChanged(EntityEntry entity);
}


public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<User> {

  private static bool ConfigurOverridesSet = false;
  protected static readonly List<IEntityFrameworkOverrides> EFOverrides = new List<IEntityFrameworkOverrides>();

  public static void ConfigureOverrides(IEnumerable<IEntityFrameworkOverrides> overrides) {
    if (ConfigurOverridesSet) {
     throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot set overrides on SplitFamContext More than once.");
    }
    EFOverrides.AddRange(overrides);
    ConfigurOverridesSet = true;
  }

  public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) 
    :base(options) { }
}
```

And then in Startup I just did this:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddMvc();

  var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

  services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
  services.AddSingleton<IUserContextProvider, MvcUserContextProvider>();

  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => {

  options.UseNpgsql(
    Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationContext"));
  });

  services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

  builder.Populate(services);
  this.ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();

  // Create the IServiceProvider based on the container.
  return new AutofacServiceProvider(this.ApplicationContainer);
}

public void Configure(
  IApplicationBuilder app,
  IHostingEnvironment env,
  ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
  IApplicationLifetime appLifetime) {
  if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  loggerFactory.AddConsole(this.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
  loggerFactory.AddDebug();

  app.UseMvc();

  var userContexProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IUserContextProvider>();
  ApplicationContext.ConfigureOverrides(new List<IEntityFrameworkOverrides>(){
    new SoftDeleteOverrides(userContexProvider),
    new TrackCreatedOverride(userContexProvider),
    new TrackModifiedOverride(userContexProvider)
  });

  appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => {
    this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose();
  });
}
```

Probably needs some tweaks and I don't love it but it could be a work around until you can inject services into DbContext...

Another approach you could use is to get a static HttpContext like in older versions of MVC.  Solution found here:  https://www.strathweb.com/2016/12/accessing-httpcontext-outside-of-framework-components-in-asp-net-core/

I still haven't tried the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity yet either nor do I know of any problems with the same.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelYoung I will give that a try.